# Pairing last element from previous pair as first in next pair

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I try to create a array of pairs

my input is

`[1,2,3,4,5]`

and I want to achieve this output:

`[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5]]`

do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: show you code you currently have

Comment: `let result = zip(arr, arr.dropFirst()).map { [$0, $1] }` or using the linked Q&A, `let result = arr.pairs.map { [$0, $1] }`